# XAMPP httpd.conf setup to allow for mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, xampp

I recently inherited a unfinished CodeIgniter project from a company that has sub-contracted me to complete it. I'm having some trouble with the mod_rewrite rules that the previous dev has implemented as I am unable to view the project on my localhost.

From what I can gather the rules applied are just to get rid of the "index.php" portion of the URL. The project works perfectly live so I believe that the issue lies with the way I have set up my xampp httpd.conf file. As per instructions found on this site and other sources I have mad the following changes to the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Me/Documents/Github"
<Directory "C:/Users/Me/Documents/Github">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I go to localhost and click on the project I am just getting a 404 error. I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and don't know how to proceed. Can you see an issue with the way I've set up the httpd.conf file? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Added the rewrite rules being used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

SetEnv ENVIRONMENT development
```

Comment: Looks ok so far. To test if your .htaccess is loaded, insert some jibberish there to see if you get a HTTP 500. If you don't, your .htaccess is ignored. Otherwise you have to post your rewrite rules here so we can see if something's wrong with them.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I did get the 500 error so it looks like the htaccess file is being found. What I don't understand is that everything works perfectly in the live environment so surely the project files themselves are fine but my xampp configuration is incorrect? I've added the rewrite rules above for you to have a look at. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue and can't get it to work on my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a wild guess but when I look at my Xampp apache config it has

```
 ..
 allow from all
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Most likely that's not the problem. If it's a project which is developed for some time already (as the OP mentions), an allow/require issue would have popped up much earlier.